# How to open a website from iPad?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an Air app for an iPhone, and I want to have a button that gives you the functionality of going to a web page, that means, minimizing the app and execute the link to that page, how can I do that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the navigateToURL method when the button is clicked / tapped. Refer details of the API at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cba.html

Comment: Yeah, that is the correct answer. Guys, next time, read that I'm making the app with Air.